# Jersey client doesn't follow redirects

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have "users" resource defined as follows:

```
@Path("/api/users")
public class UserResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addUser(User userInfo) throws Exception {
                String userId;
        User existing = ... // Look for existing user by mail
        if (existing != null) {
            userId = existing.id;
        } else {
            userId = ... // create user
        }
        // Redirect to the user page:
        URI uri = URI.create("/api/users/" + userId);
        ResponseBuilder builder = existing == null ? Response.created(uri) : Response.seeOther(uri);
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Path("{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUserById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return ... // Find and return the user object
    }
}
```

Then, I'm trying to test user creation using Jersey client:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));

User userInfo = UserInfo();
userInfo.email = "test";
userInfo.password = "test";
client.resource("http://localhost:8080/api/users")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(User.class, userInfo);
```

I get the following exception:

> SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.colabo.model.User,
>   and Java type class com.colabo.model.User, and MIME media type
>   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 was not found

And this is the trace of the HTTP request:

```
1 * Client out-bound request
1 > POST http://localhost:8080/api/users
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > Content-Type: application/json
{"id":null,"email":"test","password":"test"}
1 * Client in-bound response
1 < 201
1 < Date: Tue, 03 Jul 2012 06:12:38 GMT
1 < Content-Length: 0
1 < Location: /api/users/4ff28d5666d75365de4515af
1 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
1 <
```

Should Jersey client follow redirect automatically in this case, and properly unmarshall and return a Json object from the second request?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: You are not getting a redirect code (3xx), but a created (201). How is the client supposed to redirect? Also I think you should add @Produces to the post method

Comment: @EugenioCuevas but the response contains "Location" header, isn't this enough? I tried adding Produces annotation, but this didn't help either.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue and resolved it by following client filter

```
package YourPackageName;


import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class RedirectFilterWorkAround implements ClientResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext, ClientResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        if (responseContext.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Response.Status.Family.REDIRECTION)
            return;

        Response resp = requestContext.getClient().target(responseContext.getLocation()).request().method(requestContext.getMethod());

        responseContext.setEntityStream((InputStream) resp.getEntity());
        responseContext.setStatusInfo(resp.getStatusInfo());
        responseContext.setStatus(resp.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Now while in other class where you are creating Client as

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
```

Apply this filter class as

```
client.register(RedirectFilterWorkAround.class);
```

This is working with Jersey 2.x
Found these pointers on SO :p

Comment: Does this work for you? I'm facing the same problem as OP (with PUT instead of POST) and this filter produces the error `Entity must not be null for http method PUT.` I tried to transfer the entity from the requestContext to the next request as such: `resp=requestContext.getClient.target(responseContext.getLocation()).request().put(entity)` but had issues with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Follow redirects means following [30x](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) status code redirects. What you have there is a [201](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.2) response, that is not a redirect. You can write a [ClientFilter](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/ClientFilter.html) that will follow the location header if 201 is returned.

Comment: Any pointers on how to create a ClientFilter that follows redirects ? ( I'm using a 2.5 client)