# Jersey client for accessing web services having Single Sign-On authentication [ webSSO / SSO ]?

Tags: web-services, rest, single-sign-on, jersey-2.0

I have a web service for which the user authentication is provided by web browser Single Sign-On authentication method , through which a human user is automatically logged in with his/her company email ID from a web browser.

I have written a java Jersey 2.x client (a non human consumer of web service). In client code I am using HttpAuth as

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("ENTER_USERNAME_HERE", "PASSWORD_HERE");
```

But the client fails stating the HTTP status code as 302 (redirection error)
Then I used curl for the same and received the response as an HTML page stating
The document is moved here(<-- a link containing websso url to my resource).
After searching on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305520/jersey-client-doesnt-follow-redirects) I enabled the FollowsRedirection feature for my jersey client and now the error is changed to

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
```

Any pointer on how to handle this authentication problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was finally resolved , so I am going to answer my own question,

After all the RnD , it was clear that there isn't any sophisticated way for passing (Authenticating) the WEb SSO (Single Sign-On) from jeresy 2.x client code.
Although I found some interesting articles regarding `kerberos` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572323/single-sign-on-to-secure-rest-apis-and-internal-web-based-system) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html).

So , finally 
I created an other URL path as
`/AuthWithCert` CONTEXT in server proxy configuration and added the requests coming from this path as an exclusion in webSSO login conf.
So automatically the authentication was pointed to default (`HttpBasic Client Auth`) without any redirection error and the client worked fine.